# AJAX request to perform search in Flask

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make a search feature with AJAX. I mean, I click in the button to the right of an input box, and then it shows the results without reloading the page. See here my **HTML** to show that input form (frontend) in the current home page.

```
<li>
    <p><input type="text" size="18" name="query"><br>
    <span id=result>?</span>
    <p><a href="/search" id=search>Go!</a>
</li>
```

Then I created a **javascript** file to make that AJAX request to be performed. See:

```
$(function() {
var submit_form = function(e) {
  $.getJSON('/search', {
    query: $('input[name="query"]').val()
  }, function(data) {
    $('#result').text(data.result);
    $('input[name=query]').focus().select();
  });
  return false;
};
$('a#search').bind('click', submit_form);
```

My "/search" route is defined as so:

```
@home_blueprint.route('/search')
def search():
    sql = 'SELECT "publicName", "completeName" FROM "politics" WHERE '
    politicDict = request.args.get('query', 'No results were found', type=text)
    print politicDict # It returns 'No results were found'
    return render_template('home.html')
```

So, let's suppose I wrote "diogo" in that input form (so its val() should be "diogo"). So, the url request should be something like this:

http://localhost:5000/search?query=diogo

and here it is what I get:

http://localhost:5000/search, and for that reason I get politicDict (**python** file) to be 'None' instead of 'diogo'

Any help would be much grateful,

Best regards.

Edit: fixed Python formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might be very late but it can help others who are stuck on the similar problems! Some of your mistakes are:

1. you are not calling [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) which prevents the default behavior.
2. You are not return a proper JSON data back from your flask method as you should make two different methods, one for rendering your page and other to get the data(API)

Here, I propose my solution:

HTML and Javascript code

```
<html>
  <li>
    <p><input type="text" size="18" name="query"></p>
    <br>
    <span id=result>?</span>
    <p><a href="/search" id=search>Go!</a></p>
  </li>
  <div id="result">
   Results will appear here!
  </div>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#search", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var search_term = $('input[name=query]').val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(search_term )
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{url_for('search')}}",
                data: { "query": search_term },
                success: function (response) {
                        $("#result").empty(); //remove whatever is there and append whatever is returned
            $("#result").append(response.result) //append whatever you want to append
                }
            }
        )
    });
</script>
```

flask code

```
@home_blueprint.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@home_blueprint.route('/search')
def search():
    sql = 'SELECT "publicName", "completeName" FROM "politics" WHERE '
    politicDict = request.args.get('query') # get the data
    print politicDict # It returns 'No results were found'
    return {"result":politicDict} #you can return whatever result you get from SQL here but I am just
                       # returning the data you sent.
```